# Rewrite URL: QUERY_STRING and redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite url from

> **example.com/test/?var=somevalue** or **example.com/test/page1.html?var=somevalue**

to

> **example.com/test/somevalue/**

Here is the code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test/$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=([a-z]*|[a-z]*\-[a-z]*)$
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/%1/page1.html? [R=301,L]
```

This for now only works with url example.com/test/?var=somevalue and what I can't get to work is url with page[1-9][0-9]*\.html before query_string

Comment: So does the path `/test/somevalue` actually exist, or are you trying to force inbound urls of the query string form to be redirected into the SEO form, then still internally rewrite them?  Please rephrase this to indicate: 1) what URL your end user sees 2) whether or not that's the _only_ permitted end user URL 3) what URL your server ultimately receives and processes

Comment: end user sees `/test/`,`/test/page1.html`,`/test/somevalue/`, `/test/somevalue/page1.html`
all what I need is if query_string contains var, then it will be redirected to `/test/(var value)/page1.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test/(page[1-9][0-9]*\.html)?$
```

I think that's what you're looking for, piecing together the regex you already used with the one you described at the bottom of your query. But I'm a little shocked your rewrite rule worked at all.  I would expect something more along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/?])*\?([^&]+&)*var=([^&]+) /test/%3/page1.html
```

But I don't write that many RewriteRules, so I could be wrong.

Comment: actually this helped `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test/([a-z]*\/|[a-z]*\-[a-z]*\/)(page[1-9][0-9]*\.html)?$`

Comment: I thought it might.  did it fix your problem?

Comment: yes, totally forgot about brakets when I was trying to fix it before posting question.
thank you all for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /test/([^\?]*)\?var=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /test/%3/%2?%4 [L,R=301]
```